# Index was outside the bounds of the array in - C#

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file that is setup like this:

```
1 Username Email MD5Password PlainPassword
```

Now I want to put this .txt into SQL, so I have this code:

```
string[] SQL = line.Split(' ');

dynamic ID = SQL[0];
dynamic Username = SQL[1];
dynamic Email = SQL[2];
dynamic Password = SQL[3];
dynamic PlainPassword = SQL[4];

string lines = "INSERT INTO `dbsearch`(`username`, `password`, `email`, `extra`) VALUES ('" + Username + "', '" + Password + "', '" + Email + "', '" + PlainPassword + "')";
```

But some lines in my .txt file doesnt have a password or plainpassword, so I get this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in Search SQL Creator.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? You're accessing an index which is outside the bounds of your array. Are you sure you have 5 elements?

Comment: You can run the debugger and add a breakpoint at the first line. Please show the content of "SQL" at the execution.

Comment: Like I said, most of the times I have 5 elements, but sometimes there is not. So how can I just make it empty if there is not a element?

Comment: just check the size of `SQL`, and if it contains 5 values do as now, and if only 3 set default values for P and PP.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` when the values are clearly `string`?

Comment: Quite off-topic, but do you think inserting some plaintext password into a DB is a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not sure whether you have the last element, you can check before accessing it inside the array:

```
string[] sql = line.Split(' ');

dynamic id = sql[0];
dynamic username = sql[1];
dynamic email = sql[2];
dynamic password = sql.Length >= 4 ? sql[3] : null;
dynamic plainPassword = sql.Length == 5 ? sql[4] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use LINQ:

```
string[] sql = line.Split(' ');

string id = sql[0];
string username = sql[1];
string email = sql[2];
string password = sql.Skip(3).FirstOrDefault();
string plainPassword = sql.Skip(4).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This would redundantly enumerate the collection twice.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Possibly. At worst though this is only for 7 + 2 elements. Accessing 9 elements to get 2 from an array is hardly a performance issue. Besides, many of the LINQ operators recognize that they are iterating over arrays and do direct access.